# using MRTK implementation add listener codes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

```
contactDetection.onTouch.AddListener(MyCallback);
contactDetection.onFirstTouch.AddListener(DoThisOnFirstTouch);
contactDetection.onLastUntouch.AddListener(DoThisOnLastUntouch);
```

I was using these lines of code for HPTK for oculus, but I want to do the same for MRTK. Can someone help me? How can I do that?

I was trying to know when my object was touches and left. When my cursor first touches my object, then when it lefts the touch of my object.

Answer (score 0):

In MRTK, you can use Interactable or ObjectManipulator to detect if an object is being touched. For more information, you can refer [Buttons - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/button?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) and [Object manipulator - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/object-manipulator?view=mrtkunity-2022-05). Regarding whether it's the first touch, maybe you can add a counter manually.